# How to notify QtQuick2 TableView that its contentHeight has changed to update its scroll bars?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a `TableView` where each cell is represented by a `Label` delegate. This `Label` component has `wrapMode` set to `Text.Wrap` meaning that its height can change when the `TableView` is resized.

However, the `TableView` doesn't seem to be aware that its `contentHeight` has changed because of the wrapping, hence the scroll bars do not update. This is shown below:

[image: scroll bar not updating after content height has changed]

How to notify `TableView` that its contentHeight has changed so that the scroll bars update accordingly as the view is being resized?

QML code to create table shown above:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 220
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TableView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        columnWidthProvider: () => width/2
        onWidthChanged: forceLayout()
        onHeightChanged: forceLayout()

        model: TableModel {
            TableModelColumn {display: "key"}
            TableModelColumn {display: "value"}
            rows: [
                {key: "first name", value: "Freida"},
                {key: "last name", value: "Vandervort"},
                {key: "date of birth", value: "03/05/1989"},
                {key: "street address", value: "977 Kuvalis Mountain"},
                {key: "city", value: "Lynchville"},
                {key: "country", value: "Dominican Republic"},
            ]
        }

        delegate: Label {
            padding: 10
            text: model.display
            wrapMode: Text.Wrap
            background: Rectangle {border.color: "black"}
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to store the heights of the delegates in an array and use this to calculate the `contentHeight`. This array needs to be updated whenever the delegate changes its size.

```
TableView {
    //store delegate heights
    property var delegateHeights: Array(model.rowCount).fill(0)

    //use stored delegate heights to calculate content height
    contentHeight: delegateHeights.reduce((total, height) => total + height, 0)

    delegate: Label {
        //update stored delegate heights when delegate size changes
        onHeightChanged: view.delegateHeights = view.delegateHeights.map((el, index) => index === row ? height : el)

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```